# Creating sum of many columns from names in one column

Tags: r

I have a large data frame where I have one column (Phylum) that has repeated names and 253 other columns (each with a unique name) that have counts of the Phylum column. I would like to sum the counts within each column that correspond to each Phylum.

This is a simplified version of what my data look like:

```
     Phylum    sample1    sample2    sample3 ...    sample253
1    P1        2          3          5              5
2    P1        2          2          10             2
3    P2        1          0          0              1
4    P3        10         12         3              1
5    P3        5          7          14             15
```

I have seen similar questions, but they are for fewer columns, where you can just list the names of the columns you want summed. I don't want to enter 253 unique column names.

I would like my results to look like this

```
    Phylum    sample1    sample2    sample3 ...    sample253
1   P1        4          5          15             7
2   P2        1          0          0              1
3   P3        15         19         17             16
```

I would appreciate any help. Sorry for the format of the question, this is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow (rather than sleuthing).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your starting file looks like this (`test.csv`):

```
Phylum,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample253
P1,2,3,5,5
P1,2,2,10,2
P2,1,0,0,1
P3,10,12,3,1
P3,5,7,14,15
```

Then you can use `group_by` and `summarise_each` from dplyr:

```
read_csv('test.csv') %>% 
  group_by(Phylum) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

(I first loaded tidyverse with `library(tidyverse)`.)

Note that, if you were trying to do this for one column you can simply use `summarise`:

```
read_csv('test.csv') %>% 
  group_by(Phylum) %>% 
  summarise(sum(sample1))
```

`summarise_each` is required to run that function (in the above, `funs(sum)`) on each column.

Comment: I received the error: `summarise_each()` is deprecated. 

So instead I used summarise_all() and it seemed to work! Thank you :)

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that error ``summarise_each()` is deprecated.
Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
To map `funs` over all variables, use `summarise_all()`` ... thanks for pointing that out :)